# On a Robin Forman's remark on combinatorial simplicial complexes

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, big-list, simplicial-complexes

In a very captivating [introduction](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-User-s-Guide-to-Discrete-Morse-Theory-Forman/95e96a06d60204d271c3e144c3c2f915283f1168) to discrete Morse theory, Robin Forman makes the following remark:

> ...However, that does not explain why so many simplicial complexes that arise in combinatorics are homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres. I have often wondered if perhaps there is some deeper explanation for this.

The latter enigma seems to have been [addressed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17370/why-do-wedges-of-spheres-often-appear-in-combinatorics) elsewhere on MO. I have a more neophyte question: what are practical examples of studying such simplicial complexes, and do any deep combinatorial results stem from this equivalence?

Comment: You get a lot of alternating-sum identities out of it, at least :)

Comment: I am not sure this qualifies as a "practical example," but shellable simplicial complexes are wedges of spheres of equal dimension. Björner & Wachs generalized to non-pure wedges of spheres (not all equal dimensions), partly to address questions in arrangements of subspaces.  "Shellable nonpure complexes and posets. I." *Transactions  AMS* 348.4 (1996): 1299-1327.

Comment: Here's a compelling list. I particularly like Bjorner's paper called "a cell complex in number theory". https://www.google.com/search?q="simplicial+complex"+"wedge+of+spheres"+file%3Apdf

Comment: Lovasz initiated a whole field of determining chromatic properties of graphs from the topological properties of its neighorhood complex or various hom complexes. For the original example of the Kneser graph $K_{n,k}$, Lovasz needed to compute the connectivity of its neghborhood complex, but this ends up being homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres of dimensions $n-2k$, so the connectivity is exactly $n-2k-1$ and in turn the chromatic number is exactly $n-2k+2$.

Comment: (This way of phrasing the proof was not in Lovasz's original paper, but you can read it in chapter 2 of "A course in Topological combinatorics" by Mark de Longueville)